# createOrder breaks paypal api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, paypal

When rendering a paypal button in angular like so:

```
  @ViewChild("paypalRef", { static: false }) private paypalRef: ElementRef;
  renderPaypalButton() {
    this.paypalSelected = true;
    if (this.paypalButtonRendered != true) {
      paypal
        .Buttons({
          style: {
            layout: "horizontal",
            color: "white",
            label: "",
          },
          createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  amount: {
                    value: "1000",
                    currency_code: "zar",
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
        })
        .render(this.paypalRef.nativeElement);
    }
    this.paypalButtonRendered = true;
  }
```

the PayPal pop up displays for a split second and then disappears. However, as soon as I remove the createOrder function, the PayPal pop up displays as normal. I am sure there is just something I am doing wrong, but any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the PayPal pop up displays for a split second and then disappears.

In general, look at the browser Javascript console and/or Dev Tools "Network" tab log to find the reason for the error.

> currency_code: "zar",

For this particular situation, we can see that this is not a PayPal API [supported currency](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/currency-codes/).

Generally transactions must be denominated in a common international currency such as USD instead. If the payer has a funding source in a local currency like ZAR, such as a local card, the conversion will be shown to them during checkout. You will receive the transaction currency (again, typically USD)